# Resolve Function in Overloading

Tags: c#, overloading

The case is I have the following class, for example:

```
public class SendFile
{
     public SendFile(Uri uri) { /* some code here */ }
     public SendFile(string id) { /* some code here */ }
}
```

Then, We know that if I want to resolve the constructor, I can't do it likes the following:

```
// some string defined which are called "address" and "id"
var sendFile = new SendFile(String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) ? id : new Uri(address));
```

My question is *How can I resolve this issue in a clean way, without creating an "if" branch in the code?* likes the following:

```
SendFile sendFile;
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
{
     sendFile = new SendFile(id);
}
else
{
     sendFile = new SendFile(new Uri(address));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be to add a `static` 'factory' method to `SendFile` and take care of it there:

```
public class SendFile
{
    public SendFile(Uri uri) { /* some code here */ }
    public SendFile(string id) { /* some code here */ }

    public static SendFile Create(string url, string fallbackId = null)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)
            ? new SendFile(fallbackId)
            : new SendFile(new Uri(url));
    }
}
```

The parameter naming should make clear that `fallbackId` is only used if `url` is not provided.

Comment: See link about [Factory Method](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern) design pattern

Answer (score 6):

In your version above you get the compilation error of:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.Uri'

When reading [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) it states:

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

As `string` and `Uri` do not have an implicit conversion between each other (which you also do not want as if you did why have two different constructors..),
to use the conditional operator you should do it a bit differently:

```
var sendFile = String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) ? new SendFile(id) : 
                                               new SendFile(new Uri(address));
```

Comment: I really needed to fix the compilation error: 
`var sendFile = new SendFile(String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) ? (dynamic)id : new Uri(address));`. But really, DON'T use this :) Gilad proposed a way cleaner solution.